# Svelte and Tailwind. Popout navbar not hiding table header

Tags: tailwind-css, sveltekit

Using Sveltekit and Tailwind CSS I have a popout from a hamburger menu but cannot figure out how to hide the table header.  Note from the screen shot below that the table data gets hidden but not the header.
I've tried Google but am not sure how best to phrase the issue so haven't found anything useful. Not knowing how best to ask doesn't help with ChatGPT either :)
[image: screenshot of menu not overwriting screen properly]

The CSS being applied to the table is as follows:

```
tr {
    @apply even:bg-white odd:bg-gray-300 border md:border-none block md:table-row
}

th {
    @apply bg-gray-600 p-2 text-white font-bold md:border text-left block md:table-cell
}

td {
    @apply p-2 md:border text-left block md:table-cell
}
```

and for the menu:

```
<aside class="absolute w-full bg-gray-300 border-r-2 shadow-lg" class:open>
  <button class="py-4 px-4" on:click={() => (open = false)}>
    <X />
  </button>
  <nav class="p-12 text-xl">
    <a class="block" href="/" on:click={() => (open = false)}>Today</a>
    <a class="block" href="/drivers" on:click={() => (open = false)}>Drivers</a>
    <a class="block" href="/lorries" on:click={() => (open = false)}>Lorries</a>
    <a class="block" href="/vets" on:click={() => (open = false)}>Vets</a>
    <a class="block" href="/user-profile" on:click={() => (open = false)}>Profile</a>
    <hr class="border-1 border-gray-500 cursor-pointer hover:border-red-500 duration-500" />
    <a href="/login" on:click={() => (open = false)}>Sign Out</a>
  </nav>
</aside>

<style>
  aside {
    padding-left: 20%;
    right: 100%;
    transition: ease-out 200ms;
  }

  .open {
    transition: ease-out 200ms;
    right: 20%;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu already has class `absolute` so try to increase z-index your menu by adding class `z-*`, read here  [Tailwind Z -Index](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/z-index)

Like this example:

```html
<aside class="absolute z-10 w-full bg-gray-300 border-r-2 shadow-lg" class:open>
  ...
</aside>
```

Try each level of z-index that suitable for you, or you can write class using arbitrary values like this `z-[5]` if you want.

Hope it helps.